# Class attribute resets to default after passing class as an argument in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am creating a class to set, hold and access data throughout the project. Below is my Data class:

```py
class Data:
    """This class stores project-related constants as class attributes for easy access throughout the project."""
    ORG_URL: str = "https://www.myurl.com/"
    PROJECT_NAME: str = "My Project"
    root_path: str = ""

    @classmethod
    def set_root_path(cls, new_path):
        cls.root_path = new_path
```

Below is my Main class which sets the root when run:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


class Main:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # determine if application is a script file or frozen exe
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
            application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
        elif __file__:
            application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

        data = Data()
        data.set_root_path(f"{application_path}")
        

        with Manager() as manager:
            q = manager.Queue()
            args = manager.Queue()
            print(data.root_path)                          ## prints correct path
            gui = Process(target=GUI,args=(q,args,data))
            runner = Process(target=Runner,args=(q,args,data))
            gui.start()
            runner.start()
            gui.join()
            runner.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Below is my Runner class where i am accessing the root_path:

```py
class Runner:
    def __init__(self,q,args,data) -> None:
        print("Initiating Runner")
        self.q = q
        self.args = args
        self.data = data
        print(self.data.root_path)  # prints ''
```

I tried multiple things but could not resolve it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because processes are [spawned](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) in Windows (and MacOS by default), not forked. As a result modules are reloaded when a new process is spawned, so module-level `class` statements are re-executed, and so are the initialization of class variables within.

To transfer an object across processes you should use an instance of a class rather than a class. For readability you can create a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) instead so the instance attributes can be declared in as clean a way as class variables:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Data:
    ORG_URL: str = "https://www.myurl.com/"
    PROJECT_NAME: str = "My Project"
    root_path: str = ""

    def set_root_path(self, new_path):
        self.root_path = new_path
```

Demo (run under Linux in explictly spawn mode): https://replit.com/@blhsing1/RequiredDisguisedCodewarrior

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But there is another issue, when i close my tkinter window the main program does not terminate. I tried by setting daemon as True for both the Process but still its the same.

Comment: Glad to be of help. What you ask about now is beyond the scope of this question and should be asked as a separate question so people can better help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm suspecting that the error lies in using the classmethod-decorator. Here is something useful:

Instead of accepting a self parameter, class methods take a cls parameter that points to the class—and not the object instance—when the method is called. Since the class method only has access to this cls argument, it can’t modify object instance state. That would require access to self . However, class methods can still modify class state that applies across all instances of the class. [source](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/)

So your statement

```
data.set_root_path(f"{application_path}")
```

Doesn't actually change the parameter in that instance, at least according to the explaination.

So your method would have to look like:

```
    def set_root_path(self, new_path):
        self.root_path = new_path
```

Comment: The class method is not the problem. The OP's code would work just fine under UNIX in fork mode. Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/LimpingPushyFreesoftware